# Updating DateTime in doctrine impossible

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

I would like to update `DateTime` with Doctrine in my controller.

The aim of page is to upload photos on a database. Only one upload by user is allowed.

Everything is working but the `DateTime` is not persisted in the database.

Here is my controller:

```
public function delationAction(Request $request)
{
    $_SESSION['AriseID']="boucas2013";

    $finder = new Finder();
    $finder->in('/var/www/html/separatiiste/web/uploads');
    $photos = array();

    foreach ($finder as $file) {
        array_push($photos, $file->getRelativePathname());
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $b=1;

    $user = $this   ->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('SlothBundle:User')
                    ->findOneBy(array('ariseID' => $_SESSION['AriseID']));   

    if ($user==null) {
        $b=0;
        $user = new User();
        $user->setAriseID($_SESSION['AriseID']);
    }

    $interval= date_diff(new \DateTime(),$user->getLastPost())->d;
    var_dump($user->getLastPost());

    if ($interval>0||$b==0) {


        $photo = new Photo();

        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(new PhotoType(), $photo)->getForm();

        if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($photo);
            $user->updateLastPost();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $photo->upload();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sloth_default_delation'));
        }

        return $this->render('SlothBundle:Default:delation.html.twig', array(
          'form' => $form->createView(),
          'photos' => $photos,
        ));
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('SlothBundle:Default:delation.html.twig', array(
            'photos' => $photos,
        ));
    }

}
```

and there is the fonctions in my entity User

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastPost", type="time", length=255)
 */
private $lastPost;

/**
 * Get lastPost
 *
 * @return DateTime
 */
public function getLastPost()
{
    return $this->lastPost;
}

/**
 * Update lastPost
 *
 * @return DateTime
 */
public function updateLastPost()
{
    $this->lastPost = new \DateTime("now");

    return $this;
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->lastPost = new \DateTime("now"); 
}
```

every time the `var_dump` returns:

```
"object(DateTime)#344 (3) {
    ["date"]=> string(26) "1970-01-01 14:46:31.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
    ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Paris" 
}"
```

Comment: I suspect you are expecting that $user = $repo->find($id) to call the constructor and update the date time?  Doctrine does not call the constructor when loading an entity from the database.

Comment: no when i call that the entity already exist so i will modify it with "$user->updateLastPost();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();" And when it doesn't exit it call constructor with "$user = new User();"

Comment: Could you show lastPost Doctrine annotation in Entity?

Comment: lastPost annotation added :)

Comment: Do you know the `time` type contains [only time](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#time)? Is it OK for you?

Comment: Your DateTime in the DB is `1970-01-01`, which is a strong indication that you are persisting `null` to the databse, which doctrine then converts to the bogus \DateTime stamp. (And php adds the current time to your DateTime). Could you check that you are actually persisting a DateTime object and not just null?

Comment: Shouldn't lastPost's type be `datetime` instead? That's why it's probably 1970-01-01. No idea if it will fix the overall problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suspect your annotation is wrong.

You are using type `time` whereas it should most likely be `datetime`.

Try:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastPost", type="datetime", length=255)
 */
private $lastPost;
```