# FosRest : Date change is impossible with put method

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm working on a `PUT` method which allows user to update his profile. My problem is when I try to update the `birthDate` field, in the user entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Expose
 */
private $birthDate;
```

With getters and setters:

```
/**
 * Set birthDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $birthDate
 * @return User
 */
public function setBirthDate(\DateTime $birthDate)
{
    $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get birthDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getBirthDate()
{
    return $this->birthDate;
}
```

Here is my controller code sample:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FTUserBundle:User')->find($user_id);

if(null == $user) {
    $view = View::create("User not found", Codes::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}

$form = $this->createForm(new UserProfileType(), $user, array('method' => 'PUT'));
```

The error is right here, when createForm is called:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Unable to transform value for property path \"birthDate\": datefmt_format: string '' is not numeric, which would be required for it to be a valid date: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR"
```

Here's my `UserProfileType`:

```
$builder->add('birthDate', 'date', array(
    'widget'   => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'
));
```

The `birthDate` is correctly set in the  database. If I replace the return of the `birthDate` getter by a static `DateTime` object, it works fine. When I call the `$user->getBirthDate()`, before building the form, it returns me a correct `DateTime` object.

Comment: Where do you set the birthdate in the PUT case? Your setter is optional, defaulting to null, so I am unsure if it is ever set correclty.

Comment: Actually, in the User constructor, I set a default birthDate like this:
$this->setBirthDate(new \DateTime("1870-01-01"));

So I'm going to remove the null default value in my setter.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673123/updating-datetime-in-doctrine-impossible/33676942#33676942

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in my UserProfileType(). The birthDate field type must be "datetime", and not "date".